# Implementing \luaescapestring in plain e-TeX

Tags: luatex, plain-tex, lua, e-tex

I'm trying to implement `\luaescapestring` in plain e-TeX. My solution needs to be fully expandable, so that `\immediate\write\luascript{ local file = "\luaescapestring{\something}" }` works. The following code is almost there, but it consumes space characters:

```
\def\luaescapestring#1{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
  \expandafter\next\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\gobbleone
  \expandafter\detokenize\expandafter{\csname#1\endcsname}\relax}%
\def\gobbleone#1{}%
\begingroup
  \catcode`\"=12%
  \catcode`\|=0%
  \catcode`\\=12%
  |gdef|next#1{%
    |if#1|relax|else
      |if#1"%
        \"|expandafter|expandafter|expandafter
          |next
      |else
        |if#1\%
          \\|expandafter|expandafter|expandafter|expandafter
            |expandafter|expandafter|expandafter|next
        |else
          #1|expandafter|expandafter|expandafter|expandafter
            |expandafter|expandafter|expandafter|next
        |fi
      |fi
    |fi}%
|endgroup
```

A code similar to the one used in the `letterspacing.tex` package takes into account the spaces, but `\futurelet` spoils the party.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do.  The `luatex` format enables all the extra primitives of LuaTeX on loading, so `\luaescapestring` is already there.

Comment: Indeed, I'm trying to implement a similar macro outside luatex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used [OPmac trick 0153](http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#etoks), so I needed to define the `\eapply` macro only:

```
\def\tmp#1{}\edef\nb{\expandafter\tmp\string\\}  % \nb is normal backslash

\def\luaescapestring#1{\etoksA #1{\end}}
\def\etoksA#1#{\etokssB#1 {\end} }
\def\etokssB#1 #2 {\etoksC#1\end 
    \ifx\end#2\empty\expandafter\etoksD\else\space\fihere{\etokssB#2 }\fi}
\def\etoksC#1{\ifx\end#1\else\eapply{#1}\expandafter\etoksC\fi}
\def\etoksD#1{\ifx\end#1\empty\else\fihere{{\luaescapestring{#1}}\etoksA}\fi}
\def\fihere#1\fi{\fi#1}

\def\eapply#1{\ifx"#1\nb"\else\bbstring#1\fi}
\def\bbstring#1{\expandafter\bbstringA\string#1}
\def\bbstringA#1{\expandafter\ifx\nb#1\nb\fi#1}

%test:
\message{...\luaescapestring{"a"\ hah ah \a}}

\end
```

The `\message` command expands its parameter and prints `...\"a\"\\ hah ah \\a` in our example.

Note that you need not any special eTeX primitive. All is done by classical TeX.

Comment: That is a neat and useful trick. With your permission, I am going to use it in http://ctan.org/pkg/markdown to perform the escaping of strings (after I have dissected and fully understood it).

Comment: I think you meant: `\def\etoksD#1{\ifx\end#1\empty\else\fihere{{\etoksA #1{\end}}\etoksA}\fi}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Than you, I corrected it.

Comment: @Witiko Of course, you can use this. But keep in the mind some limitations. The tokenized string is processed. If the token is `\foo` then we don't know if we have to put a space after it or no. My implementation says no. So, `\foo1` or `\foo 1` (both inputs are tokenized to *the same* token list, so it is undistinguishable by TeX) is converted to `\\foo1`. Second problem: I didn't solve that ``\\`` must converted to ``\\\\``. I leave this as an exercise.